# How can I split text using pyparsing with a specific token?

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

**PLEASE NOTE:**
In [Splitting text into lines with pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564199/splitting-text-into-lines-with-pyparsing) it is about how to parse a file using a single token at the end of a line which is `\n` that is pretty easy peasy. My question differs as I have hard time ignoring last text which is started before `:` and exclude it from free text search entered before filters.

---

On our API I have a user input like `some free text port:45 title:welcome to our website` and what I need to have at the end of parsing is 2 parts -> [`some free text`, `port:45 title:welcome`]

```
from pyparsing import *
token = "some free text port:45 title:welcome to our website"
t = Word(alphas, " "+alphanums) + Word(" "+alphas,":"+alphanums)
```

This does give me an error:

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:( ABC..., :ABC...), found ':'  (at char 21), (line:1, col:22)
```

Because it gets all strings up to `some free text port` and then `:45 title:welcome to our website`.

How can I get all data before `port:` in a separate group and `port:....` in another group using pyparsing?

Comment: With pyparsing dont know but you can use split. `x = list(toke.split(' '))` and then loop and check if it equals port and take action

Comment: @DeadSec that's very impractical in production and I tend to use `pyparsing` or similar tools to handle this issue. Moreover it is not a fixed string like port. it can be anything!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting text into lines with pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564199/splitting-text-into-lines-with-pyparsing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding " " as one of the valid characters in a Word pretty much always has this problem, and so is general a pyparsing anti-pattern. Word does its character repetition matching *inside* its parse() method, so there is no way to add any kind of lookahead.

To get spaces in your expressions, you will probably need a OneOrMore, wrapped in originalTextFor, like this:

```
import pyparsing as pp

word = pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars=":")

non_tag = word + ~pp.FollowedBy(":")

# tagged value is two words with a ":"
tag = pp.Group(word + ":" + word)

# one or more non-tag words - use originalTextFor to get back 
# a single string, including intervening white space
phrase = pp.originalTextFor(non_tag[1, ...])

parser = (phrase | tag)[...]

parser.runTests("""\
    some free text port:45 title:welcome to our website
    """)
```

Prints:

```
some free text port:45 title:welcome to our website
['some free text', ['port', ':', '45'], ['title', ':', 'welcome'], 'to our website']
[0]:
  some free text
[1]:
  ['port', ':', '45']
[2]:
  ['title', ':', 'welcome']
[3]:
  to our website
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is about `pyparsing`, but for the specific use I think using regex is far more standard and simpler where instead pyparsing is probably better suited for more complicated parsing problems.

Here one possible working regex:
`^(.+port\:\d+) (title:.+)$`

And here the python code:

```py
import re
pattern = "^(.+port\:\d+) (title:.+)$"
token = "some free text port:45 title:welcome to our website"
m = re.match(pattern, token)
if m:
    grp1, grp2 = m.group(1), m.group(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `port` is a sample search keyword here we have more than 30 search keywords that user can enter.